# Circular references (like LastPostId in a forum thread) in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, circular-dependency

Suppose you have a "Thread" object that has a one-to-many relationships with "Post". In addition, you also record a "LastPostId" (to make it quicker to create a list of threads displaying the last post).

We're using assigned Guids, so we know the "Post" id ahead of time.

What's the best way to deal with this kind of circular reference in Entity Framework (code first) without using a two-stage SaveChanges()?

Comment: What do you mean 'deal with'?  If both Posts are in the object graph of the context, they'll both be saved / updated

Comment: @MarkOreta there's one Thread and one Post - the post references the Thread and the Thread references the post (via the "LastPostId") so there's a circular dependency in terms of deciding which to persist first.